# Internet Explorer issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, margins

This site has an issue with the center content portion.  For some reason in internet explorer just a couple of letters are being cut off by the sidebar.  I have no idea why, or how to fix it.  The div floats right, so I figured adding a few pixels of margin to the right would do the trick.  It doesn't...

It's this way on IE8 and I'm actually running IE 7.4 through parallels on a Mac.

Any suggestions?

http://www.thesurgicalsolution.com/

Answer (score 1):

In an `ie.css` you have:

```css
#content, .sidebar { overflow: hidden; }
```

which is clipping the text in IE only. So if you remove this rule the text will no longer be clipped. It is possible that this rule exits for a reason though, so you might want to test the whole site before just deleting it.

**Edit:** I would also fix the [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.thesurgicalsolution.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) as well as I have had unexplained rendering issues on different browsers in the past which were caused by invalid markup.

**Edit 2:** The `#content` parent `<div>` has a defined width (and is `overflow:hidden`) but a child `<div>` also has a defined width and its position makes it greater than the right edge of the parent and is therefore clipped by the parent's overflow rule. So as an alternative, you could make the `.rightbox` narrower to avoid the overflow hiding in IE.

```css
.custom #content .box-wrapper .rightbox {
    float: right;
    width: 451px; /* <-- change this */
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

Comment: Voting up because it's partially right, the only problem you have is really the width of the parent <div> of the <p> you are using, the width of 451px is actually greater than the space you have, changing this width to a smaller one will fix you problem, and you shouldn't have to do anything else. The text is not cut off on other browsers just by lunch on how the font size renders and spaces out, this is not an IE only problem really, so adjust the width.

Comment: @joseeight If you add `#content {overflow:hidden}` then the text is clipped in **any** browser. It _is_ an IE only problem because there is an extra IE specific stylesheet being included that has this rule.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that happens, but adding a `padding-left: 3px` anywhere that applies to it fixes it.